# Declaring C arrays

Tags: c, xcode, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
int array[5][3];
```

(obviously) creates a multi-dimensional C array of 5 by 3. However,

```
int x = 5;
int array[x][3];
```

does **not**. I've always thought it would. What don't I understand about C arrays? If they only allow a constant to define the length of a C array, is there a way to get around this in some way?

Comment: Look up dynamic arrays in C, as well as variable length arrays in C. The latter is only accepted in C99 and is not a feature of C++.

Comment: I'm not writing in C++, but in Objective-C. I just felt like a C array would do the job (instead of using an NSArray).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ANSI C (aka C89), all array dimensions must be compile-time integer constants (this **excludes** variables declared as `const`).  The one exception is that the first array dimension can be written as an empty set of brackets in certain contexts, such as function parameters, `extern` declarations, and initializations.  For example:

```
// The first parameter is a pointer to an array of char with 5 columns and an
// unknown number of rows.  It's equivalent to 'char (*array_param)[5]', i.e.
// "pointer to array 5 of char" (this only applies to function parameters).
void some_function(char array_param[][5])
{
    array_param[2][3] = 'c';  // Accesses the (2*5 + 3)rd element
}

// Declare a global 2D array with 5 columns and an unknown number of rows
extern char global_array[][5];

// Declare a 3x2 array.  The first dimension is determined by the number of
// initializer elements
int my_array[][2] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
```

C99 added a new feature called *variable-length arrays* (VLAs), where the first dimension is allowed to be a non-constant, but only for arrays declared on the stack (i.e. those with *automatic storage*).  Global arrays (i.e. those with *static storage*) cannot be VLAs.  For example:

```
void some_function(int x)
{
    // Declare VLA on the stack with x rows and 5 columns.  If the allocation
    // fails because there's not enough stack space, the behavior is undefined.
    // You'll probably crash with a segmentation fault/access violation, but
    // when and where could be unpredictable.
    int my_vla[x][5];
}
```

Note that the latest edition of the C standard, C11, makes VLAs optional.  Objective-C is based off of C99 and supports VLAs.  C++ does **not** have VLAs, although many C/C++ compilers such as g++ which support VLAs in their C implementation also support VLAs in C++ as an extension.

Comment: A function parameter defined as `char array_param[][5]` is really of pointer type; it really means `char (*array_param)[15]`. The type is adjusted at compile time (it's not a conversion). Note that this applies *only* to parameter definitions.

Answer (score 1):

```
 int x = 5;
 int array[x][3];
```

Yes, it does. It's a C99 variable length array. Be sure to switch to C99 mode and be sure to have `array` declared at block or function scope. Variable length arrays cannot be declared at file scope.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
const int x=5;
int array[x][3];
```

As you said x has to be a constant or else think what would happen if in the middle of the program you changed the value of x,what would be the dimension of array:(

But by declaring it constan if you change the value of x you get a compile error.

Comment: I'd say it would have the size x at the moment the array was declared, but I get the problem...

Comment: Here `x` is not a constant but only a `const` object.